# embed short video clips directly in wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, video

I'm new to working with video.  I would like to put some tiny video clips into a wordpress 3.0 site.  Each one will last a few seconds and is very small.  They're for pronunciation.  I need a way of getting them into the wordpress page.  I'd like the visitor to be able to click something and then right away hear the pronunciation and see the shape of the mouth.  I wouldn't like him to have to go to another site, or open a special video player.  I just want it to work like this: click, 5 seconds of little audio-visual with no fanfare, and then back to the page the way it was.  If he wants to play it again, fine, he should click on it again.

I'm thinking quick time?  The software I used to make my test video clip (debut video capture software) produced a wmv file.  The test file is 800 Kb.  Maybe I need to convert this to some other format?  I am running Vista.

For the heck of it I tried just plopping it on the page with the upload video button, but I found that in order to view the video, I had to say Save or Open, and then the video clip played in the Windows Media Player.  Not what I have in mind.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can embed video in many different easy ways.

1. Upload the video to youtube and simply copy the embedding code into your blog.
2. If the video is encoded in into an flv already (or you can encode it), I use flowplayer for all my clients, but implementation can be tricky if you're not a programmer.